# How to parse/extract recipients from a bunch of .eml files?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a lot of .eml files that I need the recipient from, and instead of opening one by one and copying, I want to do this more automatically.

I want to do it similar to what [this article](http://www.emlviewer.net/2012/07/how-to-convert-eml-files-into-excel.html) explains, but the output doesn't have to be in CSV - can be plain text.

Not necessarily using Python or javascript.

Comment: what have you tried so far, even for reading each .eml? You'd better show some code, and ask what you've tried and not working

Comment: I cannot access your article

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at Toxy, an open source data extraction framework for .NET. It supports eml format extraction.

```
        string path = TestDataSample.GetFilePath("test.eml",null);
        ParserContext context = new ParserContext(path);
        IEmailParser parser = ParserFactory.CreateEmail(context);
        ToxyEmail email = parser.Parse();
```

To download it, go to http://toxy.codeplex.com/releases